# Can Spark Streaming automatically discover new kafka brokers given 1 kafka broker only specified?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming application with 300 kafka brokers (host[101-301]:9092). In case there will be new broker to be added, say host302:9092, will spark streaming application automatically discover this broker? Or do I need to stop my application, update configuration and re-run the spark streaming application? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you need not reconfigure and start.

To quote from an authortive source, e.g.
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-properties-bootstrap-servers.html
the following on

> bootstrap.server properties
>
> Since these servers are just used for the
> initial connection to discover the full cluster membership (which may
> change dynamically), this list does not have to contain the full set
> of servers (you may want more than one, though, in case a server is
> down).

Comment: I confirmed your answer is right, we don't need to reconfigure and restart. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Stands to reason if you look at what high throughput is meant to be - and look at the statement dynamically. But I think it was a good question (for others as well!). Reflecting this as well. The documentation could be more explicit about this imho.

Comment: I see we both share a love of cats.